# Terminal - redirection of output to file is shortened

Tags: terminal, io-redirection

I am using command:

```
./cpp-generator > ~/log.log
```

But when I open the log.log the file is shortened. It ends in the middle of a word.
But if I run just:

```
./cpp-generator
```

in terminal, the result is whole, full output.

Comment: Is there a mention of `/dev/fd` or `/dev/std*` or `/proc/self/fd` in `cpp-generator`. Is the file also truncated if you use `./cpp-generator | cat > ~/log.log` or `./cpp-generator >> ~/log.log`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In both cases it return truncated output. I cpp-generator I use only printf and cout for output... and I search for /dev/fd (/dev/std and /proc/self/fd) and did not find anything with it...

Comment: Is it possible that `cpp-generator` or any of the log-generating process it spawns be killed or call abort(), or _exit() without getting a chance to flush its stdio buffers? (when the output goes to a terminal, the buffering is line-based instead of block-based which would explain the difference)

Comment: it is not. cpp-generator is basically client (https://github.com/mostphotos/beanstalkpp) connecting to the server  but it is one process.

Comment: Is it truncating if you run it as `stdbuf -o0 cpp-generator > log.log`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no it is not. The output is full now.

Comment: Would `strace -fe process -o strace.log cpp-generator > log.log` suggest that the process is killed (look in `strace.log`)?

Comment: lolz :D sorry the problem is that cpp-generator is never ending process - running in loop so when the job is done (in 0.12 sec so I know... ) and the process is waiting for next job, I just press ctrl + c to end it - and it will kill it. So solution is to run it like stdbuf... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as @StéphaneChazelas said the possible cause is that ./cpp-generator is killed
Terminal has line-based buffering instead of block buffering in ./cpp-generator so this is why the terminal will print the all output.

I gave ./cpp-generator enough time to print the message, but because it run in loop I always end it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> - therefore I killed it and block-based buffers does not have a chance to write out to the file...

working solution is run ./cpp-generator like this:

```
stdbuf -o0 cpp-generator > log.log
```

Thanks @StéphaneChazelas